# PostgreSQL 12 `quote_literal` function explanation

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to understand how `quote_literal()` function works.

This is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE temp_emp (
    id integer,
    name text
);

INSERT INTO TEMP_EMP (id, name) VALUES (1, 'Super Pavel');
```

When I do:

```
SELECT * FROM "public".temp_emp WHERE name like '%Pavel%';
```

I have 1 row in result.

However, when I do:

```
SELECT * FROM "public".temp_emp WHERE name like quote_literal('%Pavel%');
```

I have 0 rows in result.

At the same time:

```
SELECT * FROM quote_literal('%Pavel%');
```

returns `'%Pavel%'`.

Could anyone explain why `like '%Pavel%'` and `like quote_literal('%Pavel%')` give different results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of `quote_literal()` -- as explained in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-QUOTE-LITERAL-EXAMPLE) -- is to quote values for dynamic SQL.  Dynamic SQL means that you are putting SQL into a string.

[If you run this on different values,](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=abe4a5d2ec4cddfd47d4f1a59147463c) you will see that it includes the single quotes:

```
select str, '"' || quote_literal(str) || '"'
from (values ('abc'), ('abc def'), ('abc '' def')) v(str);
```

This returns:

```
abc          "'abc'"
abc def      "'abc def'"
abc ' def    "'abc '' def'"
```

In particular, the single quotes are *inside* the string -- the double quotes are there too, but just to illustrate the boundaries of the string.

Clearly, although your data might have `'Pavel'` embedded in them, none of your rows have `'Pavel'` with single quotes.